# Dense_Rank + Rearrange Query SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, window-functions, dense-rank

I would like use a Dense_Rank to count the total number of different Styles. However, I would like to sort the results by CustomerName. Below is the code that I've tried. It successfully counts the number of distinct styles.

Issues: Truly, I would not like to 'order by' 'styleID', I would like to 'order by' 'customername' but I need the order by 'styleID' in order to correctly count the number of distinct styles. I've also tried to add an 'order by' filter at the very end of the query, but then it doesn't come through as a running total. (instead the numbers vary -- because the windows function runs first).

```
SELECT CustomerName, StyleName,
DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY Musical_Preferences.StyleID ASC) AS RunningTotal
FROM EntertainmentAgencyExample.Musical_Preferences
JOIN EntertainmentAgencyExample.Customers USING (CustomerID)
JOIN EntertainmentAgencyExample.Musical_Styles USING (StyleID);
```

Example Data:

```
Abe, Jazz
Abe, Classical
Fanny, Rock
Dan, Jazz
Dan, Blues
```

Desired Output

```
CustomerName| StyleName | RunningTotal
Abe, Jazz, 2
Abe, Classical, 2
Dan, Jazz, 3
Dan, Blues, 3
Fanny, Rock, 4
```

With the code I have above:

```
Dan, Blues, 1
Abe, Classical, 2
Abe, Jazz, 3
Dan, Jazz, 3
Fanny, Rock, 4
```

By adding "order by" at the end:

```
Abe, Classical, 2
Abe, Jazz, 3
Dan, Blues, 1
Dan, Jazz, 3
Fanny, Rock, 4
```

Comment: provide sample data and desired output , but seems like adding `order by customername` at the very end of your query , gives you what you want

Comment: Window functions run independent of the ORDER BY of the query.  Think of a window function running in isolation and it has no bearing on the rest of the query except the needed results for that RunningTotal Column.  Though it uses the data available in the  FROM and WHERE parts of the query

Comment: added examples. ORDER BY at the end does not produce desired results.

Comment: Does count(distinct style) over (order by customer) do the job?

Comment: @salman no. it doesn't apparently in sql, one cannot add a 'distinct' before a window function. Very odd that they'd have that not built in.

Comment: @TonyCorreia, Your desired output says you are trying to run `DENSE_RANK` on `CustomerName`